# Nginx ingress controller on localhost:80 only

Tags: nginx-ingress

I want the nginx ingress controller to bind only on `localhost` instead of all interfaces.
 I've deployed with `kubespray`, in `hostNetwork` mode and the ingress pod starts with the following command:

```
 /nginx-ingress-controller
  --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx
  --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
  --udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/udp-services
  --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
  --report-node-internal-ip-address
```

I assume what needs to be changed is the following line on `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
listen 80 default_server reuseport backlog=511 ;
```

to

```
listen localhost:80 default_server reuseport backlog=511 ;
```

I've tried directly changing the file on the image, but seems like its overwritten on startup.

Questions:

- Can this be done through the configmap pased in `--configmap`?
- If not, where to make the change so that the `nginx.conf` reflects it?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding the following key-value pair to the `ingress-nginx`  `ConfigMap`:

```
bind-address: 127.0.0.1
```

`localhost` wont' work, it complains about wrong format. 
The `nginx.conf` will be updated with the following line:

```
listen 127.0.0.1:80 default_server reuseport backlog=511 ;
```

and it will listen only on the loopback interface.
T